# Google Client gives 400: RESOURCE_PROJECT_INVALID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-client

I seem to be getting 400 when using Google's official client. Just googling `RESOURCE_PROJECT_INVALID` doesn't seem to be giving much help.

I create the `credentials.json` by simply creating a service in Google Cloud IAM and creating a key. I've checked and the project ID inside the json is correct.

```py
from google.cloud import artifactregistry_v1
from google.oauth2 import service_account


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')
client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient(credentials=credentials)
client.list_files()
```

```
InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid resource field value in the request. [reason: "RESOURCE_PROJECT_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "artifactregistry.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.devtools.artifactregistry.v1.ArtifactRegistry.ListFiles"
}
]
```

credentials.json (as generated from Google)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myproject",
  "private_key_id": "cccccccccccccccccc",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\naaaaaaaabbbbbbbb=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "myservice@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1000000000000000",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/myservice%40myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Any idea on what this means/how to fix it?

Comment: Does your JSON file correct? Does the project ID present in the JSON? Is the project still active?

Comment: Yes to all. I use the vanilla file as was download from Google Cloud when creating a service key

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`list_files`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_list_files) isn't ideal.

You will need to populate `parent` and probably best done as part of [`ListFilesRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.types.ListFilesRequest).

Try:

```py
from google.cloud import artifactregistry_v1

# Using Application Default Credentails is easiest
# export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json
client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient()

# Best obtained from the environment
project = "..."
location = "..."
repository = "..."

parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}/repositories/{repository}"

request = artifactregistry_v1.ListFilesRequest(
    parent=parent,
)

page_result = client.list_files(
    request=request,
)

for response in page_result:
    print(response)
```

Although the documentation above describes this, another way to determine the correct call is to use [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) to lookup [Artifact Registry API](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest) and find [`projects.locations.repositories.files.list`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.repositories.files/list) method:

```
GET https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*/locations/*/repositories/*}/files
```

Here you can see that the method requires a `parent` property and its definition. The page also documents the response object.